# Database Type Agnostic Select Query Encapsulation class

Tags: sql, object, select, nosql, encapsulation

I am upgrading a webapp that will be using two different database types. The existing database is a MySQL database, and is tightly integrated with the current systems, and a MongoDB database for the extended functionality. The new functionality will also be relying pretty heavily on the MySQL database for environmental variables such as information on the current user, content, etc.

Although I know I can just assemble the queries independently, it got me thinking of a way that might make the construction of queries much simpler (only for easier legibility while building, once it's finished, converting back to hard coded queries) that would entail an encapsulation object that would contain:

- what data is being selected (including functionally derived data)
- source (including joined data, I know that join's are not a good idea for non-relational db's, but it would be nice to have the facility just in case, which can be re-written into two queries later for performance times)
- where and having conditions (stored as their own object types so they can be processed later, potentially including other select queries that can be interpreted by whatever db is using it)
- orders
- groupings
- limits

This data can then be passed to an interface adapter that can build and execute the query, returning it in an array, or object or whatever is desired.

Although this sounds good, I have no idea if any code like this exists. If so, can anybody point it out to me, if not, are there any resources on similar projects undertaken that might allow me to continue the work and build a basic version?

I know this is a complicated library, but I have been working on this update for the last few days, and constantly switching back and forth has been getting me muddled at times and allowing for mistakes to occur

Answer (score 0):

I would study things like the SQL grammar: http://www.h2database.com/html/grammar.html

Gives you an idea of how queries *should* be constructed.

You can study existing libraries around LINQ (C#): https://code.google.com/p/linqbridge/

Maybe even check out this link about FQL (Facebook's query language): https://code.google.com/p/mockfacebook/issues/list?q=label:fql

Like you already know, this is a hard problem. It will be a big challenge to make it run efficiently. Maybe consider moving all data from MySQL and Mongo to a third data store that has a copy of all the data and then running queries against that? Replicating all writes to something like Redis or Elastic Search and then write your queries there?

Either way, good luck!